# what do i do about this?

Tags: interface, edit-mode

[image]

everything shows up in render mode but otherwise, this is all I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you set a [Clipping Region](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/regions.html) by mistake. Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to cancel it.

Comment: that worked! thank you for the help